# Can't Set Keyframes for Unreal 5 on CineCameraActor in LevelSequenceActor

Tags: animation, rendering, keyframe, unreal-engine5

I am trying to animate a camera path in Unreal Engine 5. I set the keyframe to change whenever the object is moved or altered. I set a keyframe but whenever I try to change anything it resets into its starting position. The selected object in the viewport is the camera (CineCameraActor).
[image]

But whenever I change anything with the camera, it doesn't save the position in the keyframe. This is what happens when I change the pitch of the camera.
[image]

And this is what happens when I change the X location.
[image]

Whenever I change the camera position at all and then move the playhead through the timeline for the LevelSequenceActor, the camera loses all edits that I performed on the camera.
[image]

So in short, how do I get the timeline keyframes to save my camera movements?

Answer (score 0):

You need to position the playhead first and then position the camera. At the moment you are doing things back to front. Get the playhead in the position where you want the camera to change and then move the camera afterwards, this should then auto generate the key frames on the timeline. If you then move the playhead back to its starting position and scrub along you should see your camera view changing.